# What's the preposition of "style"?

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

What's the suitable preposition for the word 'style'?

For example:

I want to do this job in/with/on Asian style.

I mean the shorter form of this sentence: I want to do this in the particular way that an Asian person do it.

Is it correct to use the word 'style' for such purpose?If yes, what's the preposition before it?

- (I am new to this specific community of stackexchange, please excuse me and inform me, if this question is not suitable for english.stackexchange)

Comment: In many contexts *(We eat French style, We do it doggie style, etc.)*, any preposition is either unnecessary or positively undesirable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers great point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **in** Asian style - to show what design, manner, method they followed

2) **with** Asian style - this can mean 1 or

to show it was done in some spectacular, special fashion

I'd prefer to use "with" only for the 2nd alternative for consistency, by adding more context leading toward it:

*I want to complete this job with Asian style **and pizzaz**, really **putting on the [Asian] Ritz.***

To understand my terms, go to Google Books

http://books.google.com/

and search for these entire lines:

**pizzaz slang**

**"putting on the Ritz" idiom**

Comment: Would you please explain me the bold words: pizzaz, Ritz ...
I am confused with your last sentence.
I used google translate, I found nothing valuable about them.
Are they special nouns such as "Jack" "England" "John" ... or they have meaning?

Comment: @Milad R I've edited my answer, to find the slang word and the idiom used.

Answer (score 1):

'In' or 'with' are your best choices.  Some prepositions such as 'within' or 'from' might work, but not with the context as you have described it.  Do not forget the article.

> "I want to do this job in an Asian style."
>
> "I want to do this job with an Asian style."

Use of the adjective 'Asian' with the noun 'style' is acceptable use.  The context of 'job' may or may not be strange when used with 'style'.